# convert array (n,1) of array (x,y) to array (n,x,y)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm Beginner in `Python` but i want convert an array by this shape `(1100,1)` that contain arrays with `(100,50)` shape, to an array by this shape `(1100,100,50)`, How I Can This Conversion?

```
X.shape
>> (1100, 1)
X[0][0].shape
>> (100, 50)
```

Comment: what is the type of the `(100,50)` arrays ?

Comment: If all the arrays have the same size, then `np.stack(X[:,0])` should work.

Comment: TBH, I couldn't even imagine how this is possible.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ. Thanks for attention. Type of X(1100,1) and (100,50) are `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @hpaulj. Very Thanks. This is work and my problem solved.

Comment: Based on [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) what you're describing is not possible. by default, An ndarray cell cannot contain an other ndarray.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ, `X` is an object dtype array.  It can contain arrays or any other kind of Python object.  But if the elements are all arrays of the same shape, it should be possible to convert it to a multidimensional numeric dtype array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work and solved problem:
`np.stack(X[:,0])`